# Не устанавливается VS

Tags: visual-studio

Не могу установить VS. Столкнулся с такой проблемой впервые.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть много причин. Фаервол, корпоративная прокси, ркн, ркп.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Понял ошибку. Из-за региона не удавалось скачать

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).